# Scrolling transcript, scrollTop, callback function

Tags: function, callback, scroll, scrolltop

Here I'm running a transcript, which also highlight's on the current word. The problem as the transcript scrolls upward and the text loses view so does the highlight. What I would like to happen is when the highlight gets to the top of the box it should stay in view on the top line with out disappearing upwards. Can you help???

```
function runTransript() {

//var player = _V_('video');
 //var videoCurrentTime = player.currentTime();

var transcriptSpeed = 300; //videoCurrentTime; 

transcriptSpeed *= $("#transcript .full-transcript").parent().height();

$("div").css({ top: $(this).parent().height() + 'px' });
$("div").animate({top: -$(this).height() }, transcriptSpeed, 'linear');
$(".transcript-text").each(function(index){

    var curObj = $(this);
    var interval = $(this).attr('time');

    curObj.delay(interval).animate({color: '#5c9127'}, 100, function() {
        $(this).prev().removeAttr("style").prev().removeAttr("style").prev().removeAttr("style");
    });

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

function runTransript() {

```
var player = _V_('video'),
    videoCurrentTime = player.currentTime(),
    lineCount = 1,
    transcriptSpeed = videoCurrentTime;

transcriptSpeed *= $("#transcript .full-transcript").parent().height();

$("div").css({ top: $(this).parent().height() + 'px' });
$("div").each(function(index){

    var curObj = $(this);
    var interval = $(this).attr('time');

    curObj.delay(interval).animate({color: '#f0e53d'}, 100, function() {

        var pos = $(this).position();
        console.log(pos.left);
        if(parseInt(pos.left) == 15 && index > 0){
            $("div").delay(2000).animate({top: "-"+parseInt(lineCount*35)+"px" }, 'slow', 'linear');
            lineCount++;
        } 
        $(this).addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active').removeAttr("style");
    });

});
```

}